# Unix command to find and replace a string and to list all the files where the string has been replaced

Tags: unix, sed

I need to replace a string in all files starting from the name file_* in my current directory.

For e.g/:

```
cat file_1
test1
test2
test3
```

```
cat file_2
test4
test2
test3
```

I want to replace `test2` with `test100` from both the files in my current directory.

The following command finds and replaces the string but does NOT list the files that have been modified.

```
find . -name '*file_*'|xargs sed -i 's/test2/test100/g'
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I want to display all the file names that have been modified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only list files that have actually been modified (assumes Linux):

```
find . -name '*file_*' -exec sh -c \
  'md5Before=$(md5sum "{}"); 
    sed -i "s/test2/test100/g" "{}";
  [ "$(md5sum "{}")" != "$md5Before" ] && echo "{}"' \;
```

On OSX, replace `md5sum` with `md5` and use `-i ""` rather than just `-i`.

Note that comparing last-modified timestamps (`stat -c %Y` on Linux, `stat -f %m` on OSX) is NOT an option in this case, because `sed -i` will *rewrite* ALL files, even if their *content* wasn't modified.

---

**Update**: @Jonathan Leffler suggests a more concise and elegant alternative:

```
find . -name '*file_*' -exec sh -c \
  'grep -l "test2" "{}" && sed -i "s/test2/test100/g" "{}";' \;
```

- `grep -l` lists (outputs) the input filename, but only if a match was found (and exits as soon as the *first* match is found)
- the (silent) `sed -i` command is then only invoked if a match was actually found (thanks to `&&`)

Aside from being shorter (and most likely faster), the added advantage is that not ALL files are rewritten -- only those that actually need it.

(The only slight disadvantage is that the search term is duplicated, but you could assign it to a shell variable and splice it into the `sed` program in both locations; if the search term were a sophisticated regex, things could get trickier, because regex support differs across utilities).

Comment: +1: The use of `md5sum` is clever.  I'd be tempted to use `grep -l test2` to list the names of the files (to be) modified, and then the silent `sed` to effect the change.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Great alternative; I took the liberty of incorporating it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
find . -name '*file_*' | while read rs
do
  echo "$rs"
  sed -i 's/test2/test100/g' "$rs"
done
```